# How can I plot a phase portrait on Ti-Nspire?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

I'm trying to graph the direction field and phase portrait of a system of differential equations, but I don't know how to. I can't seem to find any tutorials online. I can only graph slope fields.

Comment: I checked those links but I had difficulty understanding them.

Comment: Is there a certain problem in your mind?

Comment: There are many linear systems and nonlinear ones that I would like to plot such as dx/dt = 2y*x and dy/dt = x^2 + 4y just for example